# Parallel url get calls using Java spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have a list of urls and I want to hit them all in parallel and combine the result into a final Java object using Java spring RestTemplate. I'm able to achieve it buy accessing the urls in sequence, but due to performance concerns, I want to achieve them same in parallel. Looking forward to hearing your suggestions

Comment: How about running each call in a separate thread ?

Comment: Which versions of Java and Spring are you targeting?

Comment: Interesting! You can do it with an asynchrone event driven design (eg: message broker) But the phase of combining in a final java object should better be done with Spring 5.0 using the reactivity (must be reactive from A to Z). Otherwise, it will be the same as waiting the sequence to be complete. Please refer to the official [documentation](http://www.reactive-streams.org/).

Comment: How about creating some additional ULR that runs all desired URLs methods in parallel (Threads for exmple)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads to perform parallel jobs.

First, make a result data class to handle the responses of your URLs

```
public class URLResult {

    public String url;
    public String response;
    public Date responseTime;

    // Add fields whatever you need

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public Date getResponseTime() {
        return responseTime;
    }

    public void setResponseTime(Date responseTime) {
        this.responseTime = responseTime;
    } 
}
```

Then use it in your threads :

```
public List<URLResult> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public synchronized void addToList(URLResult result) {
        list.add(result);
    }

    public void hitUrl(String url) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                URLResult result = new URLResult();
                //here, connect to your url, get the result then set your URLResult fields
                addToList(result);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
```

At the end of the process, you will have a "list" of your results.

Comment: There are only two threads in this case right ( main thread and forked one )? In my ideal scenario if there are n urls, there should be n threads + 1 main thread

Comment: whenever you call hitUrl() method, another thread will be created. Just create an instance from your operation class that includes your list and hitUrl method and call hitUrl for each of your urls.